# Word Problem -- System of Equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

I think I'm doing this wrong. Can anyone help me identify the problem? Thanks.

A hardware supplier manufactures three kinds of clamps, types A, B, and C. Production restrictions force it to make 10 more type C clamps than the total of the other types and twice as many type B clamps as type A clamps. The shop must produce 250 clamps per day. How many of each type are made per day?

My system of equations formed:

a+b+c=250
c=10+a+b+c
b=2a

Comment: The second equation must be c = 10+a+b and not c=10+a+b+c

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all, your second equation should be 
$$
c = a + b + 10
$$
So essentially you get
$$
2a = b
$$
$$
c = a+ b+ 10
$$
$$
a+b+c = 250
$$
Plugging the first into the second, we get:
$$
c = 3a + 10
$$
Plugging this and the first into the third, we get:
$$
a+ 2a + 3a + 10 = 250 \Rightarrow a = 40
$$

Therefore, $\boxed{a = 40, \ b =80, \ c = 130}$.